# C++ Read int from file with each number separeted by comma

Tags: c++, file

I'm quite used to file manipulation with C, but now I'm learning C++, and I working on a project where theres a .txt file with integer values, each separeted by a comma, in the following way:
    00,01,02,11,45,00,55,16,00

What are the most efficient ways to read each int and store them in a vector?

Comment: Are all values in base 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getline` with a custom separator to split the input, then convert and push.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    istringstream in{"00,01,02,11,45,00,55,16,00"};
    string num;
    vector<int> values;

    while(getline(in, num, ','))
    {
        values.push_back(stoi(num));
    }

    for(auto i : values)
       cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it should work, but I'm facing a compilation error saying that stoi is not a member of std, even though I using the c++11 flag. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using the TDM-GCC 32 bits, with the Eclipse Helios IDE. Also, my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I managed to get it to work. I had to install a 64 bits compiler and use the flag -m64 to compile it. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

C++ has the function `getline` which allows you to read from a stream until a specified delimiter is found. For that you can build a string stream from the input string, then use getline to read each token.

Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string numbers = "00,01,02,11,45,00,55,16,00";
  stringstream sstream(numbers);
  string token;
  vector<string> result;
  while(getline(sstream, token, ',')){
      result.push_back(token);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works nicely, and should be quite fast.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

   std::string input = "00,01,02,11,45,00,55,16,00";
   std::vector<int> output;
   std::string holder;
   for (auto it = input.begin(), end = input.end(); it != end; ++it) {
      if (*it != ',') 
         holder.push_back(*it);
      else {
         output.push_back(std::stoi(holder));
         holder.clear();
      }
   }

   // Print the output to demonstrate validity
   for (auto it = output.begin(), end = output.end(); it != end; ++it) {
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the number without extracting strings first.

```
int number;
std::vector<int> values;
while (inFile >> number) {
    values.push_back(number);
    inFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
}
```

Instead of ignore you can also use:

```
char comma;
inFile >> comma;
```